# Using variable as text in Text element immediately activates onTextChanged

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

If I have the following code:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.10

Window {
    id: app
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    property bool txt: false

    Text {
        text: app.txt
        onTextChanged: { console.debug("Text changed") }
    }
}
```

I get “Text changed” displayed in my console as soon as the app loads, however if I set the text manually to something like

```
    Text {
        text: "Some text"
        onTextChanged: { console.debug("Text changed") }
    }
```

I don’t get the “Text changed” display in my console unless I actually have something that changes the text after the app loads.

Is this normal behaviour? Is there a way to use the variable as the text but not have onTextChanged activate as soon as the app loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's normal behaviour for qml, becuase your first **text property** is "" *(nothing)*, and when you give it a **variety** it changes from "" to `app.txt`. If you set manually text, in this case, there is nothing to change.

Comment: Thank you. That’s actually exactly what I was hoping wasn’t the case. But, to fix it, I simply created a bool property on page load and set it to true then on the first onTextChanged call, it sets it to false and ignores the rest of the onTextChanged commands allowing subsequent onTextChanged calls to run normally.

Comment: The problem is that if the initial value of `app.txt` is `""`, it will *not* trigger any `onTextChanged` signal. So I recommend you  activate your boolean after `Component.onCompleted` otherwise you might miss the first `onTextChanged` event.