# Why is this code to find the window size in QML not working?

Tags: qt, qml

I don't understand why this code does not work:

```
ApplicationWindow {

    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    minimumHeight: 1024
    minimumWidth: 768

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log(mainWindow.height + " and " + mainWindow.width);
    }

}
```

This gives a 0 and 0 read in the output. Why does this code not work?

I've tested it on another computer and it seems to work just fine. I have several Qt installations. I've tried them all and get the same result.

Comment: No it should work, which Qt and `QtQuick.Controls` ?

Comment: Qt 5.10 and QtQuick 2.9. Are you saying it should work??

Comment: I just tested exactly your code, it works indeed

Comment: Now that you mention it, I've tried the code on another PC, suppossedly the same version of everythin and it worked....

Comment: So, any ideas of what can possible be the difference?

Comment: a race condition, when your `Component.onCompleted` is executed, the window's geometry is not yet computed. Doing `onWidthChanged: print("width", width)` should show you the correct width eventually.

Comment: @GrecKo, why a race condition? there is only one root component with no children ..

Answer (score 2):

Qml Window is generated initially from *0, 0* and when it generated (with *0, 0*) the following code is executed

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    console.log(mainWindow.height + " and " + mainWindow.width);
}
```

After that *minimumHeight* and *minimumWidth* take their values. If you create button and press on it you can get your result ***qml: 1024 and 768***.

```
Button {
    id: button
    text: qsTr("Button")
    onClicked: console.log(mainWindow.height + " and " + mainWindow.width);
}
```

If you need to get values on start, you can try this code

```
onWidthChanged: {
    console.log(mainWindow.height + " and " + mainWindow.width);
}
```

or

```
onHeightChanged: {
    console.log(mainWindow.height + " and " + mainWindow.width);
}
```

It will always gives window property values and when user changes it manually. But if you need to get once, you can create a timer or check when the window get their propertys

Also, you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126373/using-variable-as-text-in-text-element-immediately-activates-ontextchanged/51126895#51126895).

Comment: It's what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are having the issue with the code, it is supposed a BUG.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    minimumHeight: 1024
    minimumWidth: 768

    onWidthChanged: {
        console.log("onWidthChanged");
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("onCompleted");
    }

    onVisibleChanged: {
        if(visible)
            console.log("onVisibleChanged");
    }
}
```

The output in `Win10 + Qt 10.1 mingw32` is:

```
qml: onWidthChanged
qml: onVisibleChanged
qml: onCompleted
```

The `width` will be changed first. And after the windows become visible, the `onCompleted` emitted.

So if you test the demo code emit `onCompleted` before `onWidthChanged`, mention the platform & compiler and report it maybe better.

Comment: Thansk for the tip, I''l check it out as soon as I can